# Remove 3D push effect on a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove all effects on a HTML Button element.
The HTML:

```
<div id="go">
<button onclick="load.update(true,cards.id);" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#header #go button{
    display:block;
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:18px;
    height:33px;
    background:url('../images/cards/go.png'); //Just an image to replace it all.
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox this works fine, but in IE (8 at least) the "push" effect of the button is still there when the button is clicked (EG the offset)
Is there any Tricks i can use to remove this effect?
Thanks in advance!
Diesal.

Comment: A duplicate question has the only correct answer I’ve found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21163265/2816199 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to get rid of the `<button>` tag completely and use a `<a href=".." />` tag in its place styled the way you want.

Just have the link do a javascript postback.

**update (from comments)**:
one example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit();">Click Here</a>
```

Of course, this requires javascript to be enabled and is considered by some to be an abuse of the anchor tag.

There are alternate versions if you are using .net webforms or jQuery.

Comment: How can i link it to well...nowhere though? if i add an Onclick event handler on the <a> tag, but how can i stop it from linking to another

Comment: another page?* sorry i;m on a new laptop and accidently pressed enter haha

Comment: Just a heads up for those attempting to be WCAG AA compliant, this is invalid markup as links should not act like buttons and vice versa.  Anchor tags with an `href` property should only be used for links that change the page or open a new tab/window.  On-page functionality should always use a `button` tag.

Answer (score 11):

you need to add background styles to :hover :active :focus as well.

```
#header #go button:hover {
border: none;
outline:none;
padding: 5px;
background:url('../images/cards/go.png');
}

#header #go button:active {
border: none;
outline:none;
padding: 5px;
background:url('../images/cards/go.png');
}

#header #go button:focus {
border: none;
outline:none;
padding: 5px;
background:url('../images/cards/go.png');
}
```

Comment: The background image is still there through all states though, just the offset and border appears.

Comment: You also need to set padding for each state.  That's whats creating the offset. But make sure you set matching padding for the normal state as well.

Comment: That fixes the border issue in IE8 but is still offsets when pressed

Comment: Have you tried line-height?  If its offsetting top -> bottom then its probably a line-height issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar experience, and was able to fix it in IE8, but not IE7.  See it working here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GmkVh/7/

**HTML:**

```
<button></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
}

/* 
   It hits this state (at least in IE) as you're clicking it
   To offset the 1px left and 1px top it adds, subtract 1 from each, 
   then add 1 to the right and bottom to keep it the same width and height
*/
button:focus:active {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have done whatever you like with the border etc., just put a span inside the button around the text like so:

`<button class="button" type="submit"><span class="buttonspan">Blah</span></button>`

Then the CSS becomes:

```
button {position:relative; width:40px; height:20px /* set whatever width and height */}

buttonspan {
height: 30px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="calculation_button">
  <button type="submit"><span>Count</span></button>
</div>

.calculation_button span {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

works for me in IE and FF

Answer (score 1):

The following helped for me in IE 10:

```
button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
}
```

It fixed the top perfectly, but left still had background bleed-though for my case. Still looks a bit odd if the user starts clicking and then moves the mouse off the button. Also obviously only enable the rule for relevant IE version(s).

Answer (score 1):

Position relative seemed to have taken care of the problem

Simply have a wrapper within the button:

So

```
<button>
   <div class="content">Click Me</div>
</button>
```

and set the DIV to position relative with top: 0, left: 0

Example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyeamaman/MkZz3/

Answer (score 1):

It's a browser behaviour, a simple solution is to use a link tag instead of button (since you're calling a javascript function).

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()" role="button"><img src="myimg"/></a>
```

If you still want to use the , I've found that there are some characteristics on each browser (in a simple debug):

- **Chrome** adds outline and padding
- **Firefox** adds a whole lot of stuff with the standart button border
- **IE** messes with the inner text position

So to fix them, you have to manipulate the pseudo selectors for the button behaviour. And for IE, a good solution is to envolve your text on a  element, and make it relative positioned. Like so:

```
<button type="button" class="button"><span>Buttom or Image</span></button>

<style>
    button,
    button:focus,
    button:active{
        border:1px solid black;
        background:none;
        outline:none;
        padding:0;
    }
    button span{
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/avNRMZ?editors=110)

[This is a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654025/prevent-clicking-button-creating-pressed-effect/32655061#32655061)