# IE 8 moves text of input button when clicked

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<input type="button" value="Button" />
```

IE indents the text down and over by 1px when the button is clicked by default. Is there any way to stop this with **just** CSS?

I'm also adding my own styles to this button, and everything is great until I click the text in the button... IE seems to ignore the :active state defined in my stylesheet. But if I click the button and not the text, IE performs the :active state. Of course the text moving issue is still present no matter what I do.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am looking for a way to disable the automatic button text displacement when clicking an input element too; have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a styled A-tag you get around this whole "pressed" state issue completely. Using `display:block` and some CSS you can style the A-tag to look exactly like any button.

Comment: I know this. But is there a way to fix the actual input button? I don't want to have to change all the input buttons to <a>'s. (This is for series of applications that all use a common stylesheet, so there would be a lot to change.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, I had the same problem and I've discovered a solution that works for all browsers.

I had two form buttons that I changed borders, font family and sizes, and padding on. When I would click them in IE they would "jump" because IE is stupid in my opinion. All other browsers seemed to style the buttons correctly and not have a display issue with the buttons moving when the user clicked them..

The solution I found was:

Style the form buttons so that each of them have an equal margin and apply a wrapper division with a position or margin that will offset to your liking.

```
   #myButton {
      font-family: Times New Roman;
      font-size: 16pt;
      border: 2px solid #f7f6f4;
      margin: 20px;
      padding:15px;
   }



   <div style="float:right;margin-right:75px;">
      <input type="submit" name="myButton" id="myButton" value="Don't Jump!" />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of IE you are using, but try [Button background shift](http://haslayout.net/css/Button-Background-Shift-On-active-Bug)
Also, check out [Remove 3D push effect on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466906/remove-3d-push-effect-on-a-button), specifically the answer from allicarn, which changes the padding from the element on :active.
Just remember to put the css in IE specific cases, like an IF block.