# Prevent <button> from shifting during click in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When you have a simple  element in a page and click it (hold down the mouse during click to see the effect) in IE8/9 then the button shifts a little down and to the right.

I'm assuming this is part of the default IE style. Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/tmcconechy/hqm59/

Comment: This doesn't actually fix your issue, in my opinion, so I'm posting as a comment. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466906/669611. They just did away with the <button> altogether. My suggestion is to stay semantic, though! The effect isn't a deal breaker is it?

Comment: No, Not a deal breaker for sure just a small detail, since my real button has its own click styling I'd like to just have that and make it look the same across browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put your text on a `<span>` and `position:relative` in it, it'll fix.

```
button span{
    position: relative;
}
```

No need for *top* and *left* definition.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it's the minimal solution

Answer (score 25):

You can stop the text moving in IE button:

```
button:active span, button:focus span {
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

<button><span>no move</span></button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQVA7/

Comment: The key here is to target the children of the button, not the button itself. This is implied, but not explicitly stated in the answer. You may also apply this to pseudo-elements: `button:active::before`, etc.

Comment: @gfullam thanks man! That bit of info to accompany the answer helped me.

Comment: As pointed out by @teefars in his answer here, it appears you only need `position: relative`, setting top/left is not required, at least in IE11

Answer (score 1):

You can apply some styles to the button. 
    button{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

Comment: padding: 0; was all that was needed to fix it for me in Firefox

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind using JavaScript, apparently this does the trick:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```