# The text inside the button flickers

Tags: html, css

This the issue only in IE. Please open the fiddle in IE only.

https://jsfiddle.net/hfmn6axh/

html:

```
<button class="Main_button find_button" type="submit">Find<span   class="icon"></span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.Main_button{
background-color: #747474;
}
.find_button {
display: inline;
padding: 7px 10px;
padding-top: 4px;
color: white;
float: left;
line-height: 25px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-right: 10px;
border: solid 0px;
height: 33px;
}
.icon {
background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center; 
height: 10px;
width: 18px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

When you click on  the button, the contents of the button changes its alignment.

Can this be solved?

Comment: Well, the button does not "flicker". The button is "going down" -- looking "pressed", like it was in Windows 95 / XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent <button> from shifting during click in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305658/prevent-button-from-shifting-during-click-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the contents of the key wrap - add `position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;`

```css
.Main_button{
    background-color: #747474;
}
.find_button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;    
    color: white;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: solid 0px;
    height: 33px;     
}
.icon {
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center; 
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;    
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
span{   
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;   
}
```

```html
<button class="Main_button find_button" type="submit"><span >Find</span><span class="icon"></span></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because IE reads the padding margin and other measurements we apply in our elements that is different to Chrome and Firefox

you can do is to detect if what browser that the user is using then

give the css compatible for it

you can use below code

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  IE specific CSS rules go here
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

hope this can help

Answer (score -1):

IE doesn't understand the `inline-block` property.

If you need the `.icon` to be `inline-block`, you can use this trick:

```
.icon {
    background:
    url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center;
    height: 10px;
    width: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

The asterisk `*` property allows other browsers to ignore the property. IE instead will overwrite the first property (`inline-block`) with the last one (`inline`).