# html button - removing 3D effect by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to do something like that: [Remove 3D push effect on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466906/remove-3d-push-effect-on-a-button), but by jQuery.
Is there any simple solution?

Comment: Why? Just use CSS; it's far cheaper; also, jQuery, or any other JavaScript, will just use CSS to achieve the same effect, so what's the point of unnecessarily involving JavaScript to do so?

Comment: But any solution from my link doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Like David said: Just use CSS. The 3D-effect is generatet by the "border"-attribute of the specific element. If you want to disable the 3d-effect on a button, you can use this:

```
input {
    border: none !important;
}
```

If you want to disable the 3d-effect only when the user clicks the button, use this:

```
input:focus {
    border: none !important;
}
```

HTML-code of the button, which the above is addressed to:

```
<input type="button" value="test" />
```