# How to Fix Text in button flicker (move to down) when click into button on IE, Firefox?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, flicker

I have this code:

```css
.button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
```

When I click into this button (button focus, active), the text will flicker (move to down a few point) on IE, Firefox browsers. How to fix it with CSS? Hope you help me. Thanks

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WorkWe/ht6pvoqz/1/

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show your problem

Comment: What versions of IE and FF are you referring to? I don't see a flicker in IE 11 or FF 37.0.1.

Comment: I don't see a flicker in Opera 28 ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypmmj2px/)), like hungerstar asks what browsers and versions of IE and FF are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. IE and firefox latest version

Comment: @robjez Updated JSFiddle

Comment: Hm - indeed, it looks like you get into so called "browser's inconsitencies" as this happens on firefox and in IE, but in different way (on IE text flickers down, while on FF it jumps slightly to the right). Have you tried some CSS resets?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text in span and give it position: absolute and it won't flick anymore!

```
<button type="button" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button>

.button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of mini-reset does the job on FF, but using extra span inside the button resolves issue on IE. Looks like we need to start considering usage of "a" tags instead of buttons:
HTML:

```
<button name="button" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}
button:active,
button:focus,
button:hover {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6pvoqz/5/) for that.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:** There is a way of dealing with IE issue - based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466906/remove-3d-push-effect-on-a-button) (@alicarn answer), but problem with this method is it creates opposite flickering on chrome. So I guess you need to pick up your poison in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to using just button tag, not span inside button. Any solution for it?

Comment: No - In this case, I'd suggest analyzing IE web inspector (F12), and viewing computed css properties, to try to find offending property (probably ms proprietary)

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of IE. This can't be fixed I think.

Instead of using **button** tag, I suggest to use **anchor** tag.