# Prevent clicking button creating pressed effect

Tags: html, css

I have a button on a form;

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="validate_form_newsletter_wide( form )"><img src="index_htm_files/btn_newsletter_wide.png" alt="Send"></button>
```

It styled using;

```
<style>

button::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
}

#form_newsletter_wide .button {
position:relative;
float: right;
cursor:pointer;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -1px;
z-index:100;
}

</style>
```

When clicked in Firefox nothing about the button changes, in Chrome I get a highlight border around the button which I can live with but in IE it's more of a pressed effect where the button almost seems to move down and right. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser behaviour, a simple solution is to use a link tag instead of button (since you're calling a javascript function).

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()" role="button"><img src="myimg"/></a>
```

If you still want to use the , I've found that there are some characteristics on each browser (in a simple debug):

- **Chrome** adds outline and padding
- **Firefox** adds a whole lot of stuff with the standart button border
- **IE** messes with the inner text position

So to fix them, you have to manipulate the pseudo selectors for the button behaviour. And for IE, a good solution is to envolve your text on a  element, and make it relative positioned. Like so:

```
<button type="button" class="button"><span>Buttom or Image</span></button>

<style>
    button,
    button:focus,
    button:active{
        border:1px solid black;
        background:none;
        outline:none;
        padding:0;
    }
    button span{
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/avNRMZ?editors=110)